# Como determinar se dois valores aleatórios estão próximos?

Tags: php

Tenho uma dúvida que gostaria de obter respostas.

Possuo uma função RAND que gera valores de 1 a 20.

O que pretendo fazer é:

```
Se o valor $rand1 tiver perto do valor $rand2
echo ok
```

Como faço para dizer "Perto de" em PHP?

Comment: Depende, o que você considera "próximo"?

Comment: Definir um valor para 'perto' e subtrair os dois números? seria isso?

Comment: Sim, Se o rand1 for 12 e o rand2 for 13, echo está perto.
Mas queria fazer isso para os 2 rands de forma facil sbaendo que ambos podem ir de 1-20.

Comment: Por mais que falta um exemplo do que tentou, não concordo dessa pergunta está negativada!

Answer (score 8):

É, o caminho é o que o @rray comentou:

```
function perto($a, $b)
{
    $limite = 2;
    return abs($a - $b) <= $limite;
}

if(perto($rand1, $rand2)) {
    echo 'perto';
}
```

Comment: Gostei desta, foi a mais acertada e resolve o meu problema. Obrigado

Comment: Poderia explicar o funcionamento do método @bfvaretto? Não sei nada de PHP, achei interessante a dúvida.

Comment: Alias + 1, entendi o que acontece no seu método.

Answer (score 1):

Tente essa lógica, não testei pôs estou pelo celular.

```
if ($rand1 > $rand2) {
    if ($rand1 - $rand2 == 1) {
        echo "Esta perto";
    }
    else {
        echo "Está longe";
    }
}
else if ($rand2 > $rand1) {
    if ($rand2 - $rand1 == 1) {
        echo "Esta perto";
    }
    else {
        echo "Está longe";
    }
}
```